# AI controlled monster vs player controlled monster stats

Tags: game-design, balance, statistics

Does anyone know if in a pokemon game does the wild pokemon have the same stats when you catch it as it did in that battle?

and to make this a more programming question ... In that type of game should the "wild" enemies have the same limits imposed on them as if they were player controlled or should the enemies be stronger that if you caught them.

This question assumes that the creature is the same level in both cases.

Comment: I can't address your main question, but the first question's answer is "yes" - in Pokémon specifically the stats it had during the battle match the stats that specific Pokémon will have once you've caught it. The differences between trained and wild of the same species is based on other factors, which are [addressed in the middle of this Gaming answer under Natures, IVs, and EVs](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/12601/pokemon-generation-iv-platinum-pearl-diamond-whats-new-since-gameboy-versio/12604#12604), which includes links to more in-depth explanation of each.

Comment: I don't get your question.

Comment: @The Communist Duck sometimes when you catch a pokemon it seems weaker than when you fought it. I want to know if this is a difficulty mechanism or player perception.

Comment: I never notice that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For balancing there is only one true answer, experiment. I don't know exactly what the different Pokemon games do, it may be different from game to game, but it seems very likely that there is a difference, as it would otherwise be quite limited what tools one have for fine tuning the difficulty.

Comment: pokemon games have only one difficulty.

Comment: @Skeith You'd still need some tuning tools to get that difficulty just right. All the more important actually to find some middle ground where most people think it's fun.